# Is there any alternate for the use of 'e' in handleChange(e) function in react component for accessing textbox value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code snippet for React component:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MarkdownEditor">
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <label htmlFor="markdown-content">
          Enter some markdown
        </label>
        <textarea
          id="markdown-content"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          defaultValue={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here in `handleChange(e)` function what is the use of `e` and how does it get derived?

Comment: It's the event, it's passed in by React when the callback is invoked (with the wrong *this*, as you'll find out). Read the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e` is the event created by the textarea HTML element when its `onChange` is triggered, in other words when changes are made to the textarea value. It contains information about which element got its valued changed (`e.target`) and to which value it was set (`e.target.value`), among other data. You can try logging it by using `console.log(e)` inside `handleChange` to see all the data it contains. (`e` often also contains method for manipulating how it behaves, such as `e.preventDefault()`, but is usually not useful in the case of events generated by textarea `onChange`.)

The name `e` is arbitrary and can be set to anything you want. The properties `target` and `value` are not.

Also note that there are many several similar `event` that can be created depending on the source of the event dispatch. An example would be clicking with your mouse somewhere, which gives you access to other data - such as the X and Y coordinates of the click - than the one dispatched when textarea `onChange` is triggered. Both are commonly referred to as `e` or `element`.

Answer (score 4):

"e" is a synthetic event parameter passed by React to your handle change function. Read more here on this: [React Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Cannot explain the full concept here, so you'll have to understand more of DOM and React, start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) with events first.